# Content provider in android

Tags: android, sqlite

My app loads cursor data and display it in listview, the data could be around 500 to 1000 entries

Actually, [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) says, in following scenarios you can use Content providers,

You want to offer complex data or files to other applications.
You want to allow users to copy complex data from your app into other apps.
You want to provide custom search suggestions using the search framework.

**You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application.**

But i'm planning to show the data via loader, as its thread safe & also i don't need to refresh list if content is changed.

Loaders does not work without content providers, so what is the alternative for me ?

Answer (score 1):

They DO work without content providers. I´ve got a CouchDB embeded in an Android application and I load the data using loaders. You can do whatever you want in there. See the example from the android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Comment: So, it means, we dont need to write providers for just to do sqlite operations??